# Sprite Kit Scene Lag when change Label Text

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, sprite-kit, lag

i need to fix this problem quickly, i got the sprite kit scene working but when i update the score the scene have a little bit of lag here is my code:

SCENE.M

```
//Update Score
    self.score +=1;
    //Score Sound
    [self runAction:scoresound];
    //Delegate Method to update score label
    [self.delegate UpdateScore];
```

ViewControllerA

```
    -(void)UpdateScore{
    scorelabel.text = F("@li", (int)scene.score;

}
```

There was the code.
 the lag is caused when i change the scorelabel text 
PD: The scrollable class is THLabel

Comment: Does this code compiles?

Comment: Why delegate and not just [self UpdateScore] ?

Comment: @sangony The UpdateScore method is on a different class

Comment: You have too little data posted to provide a meaningful guess on what the issue might be. It could be something in your label class, something to do what the delegate call, something before or after the label update or something completely unrelated.

Comment: @sangony i'm shure the problem is when i set the label text because i remove it and works fine i just don't know how to fix it

Comment: I'm not sure how or why you have set up a delegate for your label class. Try doing it without a delegate or consider if you really need a standalone class for just a label (provided that's all you have in there). Sometimes I have a problem and the only way I know how to solve it is to change my structure around a bit.

Comment: @sangony look the new code and you will know why i use a delegate

Comment: Ok. Why are you using you View Controller to process a score label? Why not use a SkLabelNode in the GameScene?

Comment: How are you setting the text. I have never seen F(" before and it appears you are missing a ) regardless.  Also if you just set the text to score label.text = @"test"; do you still see a lag? Also what do you mean scrollable class?

Comment: i think i found the problem , i use THLabel class for the scorelabel and every time i change the text the THLabel class draw it again and thats what cause the lag because the drawing code of the THLabel Have like 400 Lines Of code.